# First time deploying an express backend to Heroku 2 error code h10 Process exited with status 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

Hi I've been trying to deploy my app for the past 3 hours and I can't seem to figure out the issue. I am new to deploying to heroku and after troubleshooting for the past two hours Ive compiled a list of things I've tried from other answers

1. adding node_modules/ to .gitignore
2. creating a profile and writing web: node server.js (server.js is the file I run the server on)
3. Checking if I hard coded the port
   my code right now in server.js

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port:${PORT}`))
```

4. restarting my server with heroku ps:scale web=0 waiting a few seconds and heroku ps:scale web=1
5. redeploying my app
6. setting my npm config production to false
7. running heroku run bash and npm start I get more errors that seemingly had something to do with bcrypt in which I installed the latest version and reinstalled node_modules but now I get this

[image]

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "todolist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "hiding this"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": hiding this
  },
  "homepage": hiding this,
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

This is my config.json

```
{
  "development": {
    "database": "todolist_development",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "test": {
    "database": "express_react_auth_test",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "dialectOptions": {
      "ssl": true
    }
  }
}
```

this is my folder structure [image]

any help would be so appreciated

Comment: Looks like you're missing the db connection string. Are you sure you set it in env file?

Comment: i currently do not have a .env file do I need it to deploy? and if so how would I go about doing that? do you mean process.env? I thought that was automatically done by heroku

Comment: Well how do you specify the values you access with process.env? I think you need to set the DATABASE_URL variable. This might be helpful: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have forgotten to set your environment variables on heroku.
Just put all keys and values you have in your .env into heroku config vars and remember to add db addon in your Heroku app, if you are using mysql I'd recommend to use clearDb.

Comment: I do not have a .env file nor do I really understand the process.env sorry I'm really slow. I got my heroku app to run by running ```heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql``` and I checked my config var for DATABASE_URL and its set to postgres://kdlovcwzdgzrgi:7cb8342c1ea636be245f8c69f6c5349be4b9921b39128373fbe3168694259288@ec2-3-224-38-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d95jfgnsi2cfbf I tried making calls to the heroku URL and the only thing that works is the root ('/') if I try making an API call to ('/todos') it says relation does not exist because its not populating my db

Comment: I think I might be moving backwards to be honest right now

Comment: @andrewkim as long as you successfully added the Heroku Postgres add-on, you need to deal with DB migrations in order to have the tables on your DB.
Here is the link to work with migrations in sequelize https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html